# powershell get-contact | fl result sorting

Tags: powershell

I run

```
ps:\Get-MailContact -Identity tom | Format-List
```

I got lot of message like in attached picture

```
RunspaceId                             :
ExternalEmailAddress                   :
MaxRecipientPerMessage                 :
UseMapiRichTextFormat                  :
UsePreferMessageFormat                 :
MessageFormat                          :
MessageBodyFormat                      :
MacAttachmentFormat                    :
Extensions                             :
HasPicture                             :
HasSpokenName                          :
AcceptMessagesOnlyFrom                 :
AcceptMessagesOnlyFromDLMembers        :
AcceptMessagesOnlyFromSendersOrMembers :
AddressListMembership                  :
Alias                                  :
ArbitrationMailbox                     :
```

How can i use these list for search,sort or pick what i need only...
the attached picture is what I get from running.

[image]

Comment: At a powershell prompt type `Get-Help Sort-Object` and `Get-help Select-Object`

Answer (score 4):

Format-List turns the output into a text list, you can't use it for anything that you are asking. Use

```
$results = ps:\Get-MailContact -Identity tom
```

and then you can search with

```
$results | where-object { $_.HasPicture -eq $true }
```

and sort with

```
$results | Sort-object -Property MaxREceipientPerMessage
```

and select some properties with

```
$results | select-object -Property Alias, MessageFormat, MaxREceipientPerMessage
```

Honestly, a PowerShell tutorial would be a good place to start. Outputting to text should be the last thing you do, or not do at all, and understanding the behaviour of objects and properties like you have, is really important to everything in PowerShell

Comment: Thank you very much! That's my problem. I just start learning powershell, want use it for some daily job. but still don't know where should I start or put more time on. **Could you please show me some direction**, a book or a link

Comment: "Learn Windows PowerShell in a Month of Lunches" - by Don Jones, is the most popular and well recommended book for beginners (although I haven't read it) , and there are free videos on YouTube from that course, also by Don Jones. In fact, any video by him is likely to be a good bet.